# How to search multple database entries by 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Hi I have a database that stores ticket details line by line.  So for example if someone comes in and purchases a service, with a coupon and they purchase a gift card it breaks that transaction down into 3 seperate table entries... For example if I search the ticket number "m123"  with the query below I get the results below.

```
Select *
FROM            TicketsDetails
WHERE        (sTicket_Number = 'M123')

Ticket  Description Amount
M123    BOGO        15
M123    Service 1   -15
M123    GC Service 1    15
M123    $5 OFF      -5
```

Current query and output:

```
SELECT        t1.sTicket_Number, t1.sDescription, t1.sUserName, t2.sDescription AS Second_description
FROM            TicketsDetails AS t1 INNER JOIN
                         TicketsDetails AS t2 ON t1.sTicket_Number = t2.sTicket_Number
WHERE        (t1.sDescription = '$5 OFF') AND (t2.sDescription = 'BOGO')


M100304 $5 OFF  Kenny   BOGO
M100304 $5 OFF  Kenny   BOGO
M100542 $5 OFF  Kenny   BOGO
M103706 $5 OFF  Kenny   BOGO
M132464 $5 OFF  Dante   BOGO
M132464 $5 OFF  Dante   BOGO
M132501 $5 OFF  Dante   BOGO
M132501 $5 OFF  Dante   BOGO
M132528 $5 OFF  Dante   BOGO
M133892 $5 OFF  Raynon  BOGO
M133892 $5 OFF  Raynon  BOGO
M134067 $5 OFF  Raynon  BOGO
M134067 $5 OFF  Raynon  BOGO
```

What I'd like to do is return any ticket number that has the description "bogo" and "$5 off".   Is this possible since they are seperate entries with the same ticket number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (the logic seems to work but there might be a typo since I didn't try this on a table with your exact column names):

```
SELECT *
FROM TicketDetails as t1
INNER JOIN TicketDetails as t2
ON t1.Ticket = t2.Ticket
WHERE t1.Description='BOGO' AND t2.Description='$5 OFF'
```

The inner join should create every combination of descriptions, then look for a row that has both a BOGO description and a $5 OFF description.

Comment: This is Very close, and if it's as close as I can get thats fine.  But it displays the ticket number multiple times... any way to have it show just once?

Comment: Do you mean it is returning one row with the ticket number listed twice?  Try `SELECT t1.Ticket`.  I will update the answer.

Comment: as in it's listing `M124 M124 M125 M125` all on seperate lines.  It's much much closer.

Comment: It only does it on certain tickets... pretty strange.

Comment: Can you add those rows to the question?  That is, the rows containing M124 and M125.

Comment: sure, See above for my actual code, and output.  You will see somtimes the output is duplicated, othertimes it's not.

Comment: Can you add the rows as they exist in the table originally?  Basically the output of `SELECT * FROM TicketsDetails WHERE sTicket_Number=M100304`

Comment: Looks like a database issue... It's listing Bogo and $5 twice in the database... which is why it's doubling in the output.  your code is correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TicketDetails 
WHERE sTicket_Number = 'M123' AND 
    (Description ='BOGO' OR Description = '$5 OFF')
```

**---- EDIT ----**

Per the clarification in your comment you probably want this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TicketDetails 
WHERE Description ='BOGO' OR Description = '$5 OFF'
```

Comment: The problem is the ticket number changes on each tender... The idea is to find out who is selling our discounted "Bogo" ticket AND accepting the $5 0ff so we can have conversataions with the employees...  which means the ticket number won't always be M123